# How to set multiple date fields as value for a single column view?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

In my form, there are 3 tables, each with a column for dates field.

The date field names are:

```
CertEnd, CertEnd_1, ..., CertEnd_9
CQIEnd, CQIEnd_1, ..., CQIEnd_4
InspEnd, InspEnd_1, ..., InspEnd_4
```

When I create my view, I set up 1 column for Date and was hoping I can select all the fields stated above. But I can only select one it seems.

Then I try using formula. testing with the 1st date field from all 3 tables:

```
CertEnd;
CQIEnd;
InspEnd
```

All that did was give me the date for `InspEnd` in the view. How can I get it to show all 3 dates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use : (colon) to separate the fields in order to show all values:

```
CertEnd:CQIEnd:InspEnd
```

Comment: Thanks. I take it that colon is the equivalent for `AND` in Lotus programming?

Comment: No, the colon is used to combine the values (make a list)